# Pandas DF: How to Add Column Values Based on External Variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 2 Columns: 'Group' and 'Thing'.
'Thing' consists of fully unique values.
Each value in 'Thing' belongs to a group, which is indicated in 'Group'.

For Example:

```
Group            Thing

'fruits'        'orange'
'fruits'        'banana'
'fruits'        'mandarin'
'animals'       'monkey'
'animals'       'eagle'
```

Here is where my problem arises.

I would like to create a new column, 'Subgroup', based on a list variable I have.
This list variable categorizes SOME of the 'Thing' elements into subgroups, based on whether they are highly similar.
For example:

```
Subgroups = [ [['orange','mandarin']] , [] ]
```

In this case, the first sublist (for fruits) contains one  further sublist (populated by two of the three elements in 'Fruits'), while the second sublist (for animals) contains no further sublist; there are no similar elements.

So, I would like to:

Create a new column, 'Subgroups' which will result in each element in 'Thing' being ascribed an integer which is unique within its 'Group', UNLESS those same elements are part of the same subgroup from the 'Subgroups' variable.

If 'Thing' elements populate the same, nested subgroup list, they should be ascribed the same integer in the DataFrame.

The final output should look like this:

```
Group            Thing       Subgroup

'fruits'        'orange'      1
'fruits'        'banana'      2
'fruits'        'mandarin'    1
'animals'       'monkey'      1
'animals'       'eagle'       2
```

I've tried iterating through my list variable to see where elements overlap with ones in the 'Thing' series, but ultimately i think my Pandas knowledge is too poor to solve this.

Comment: sounds like group by would do what you want 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-groupby/

Comment: Why is the first list nested more than the second list in subgroups? is that a typo?